# What is task release time in the context of an OS scheduler

Tags: operating-system, task, scheduler

In the context of a scheduler, what it means by the release time of a task? Is it the time taken to execute the task?

Comment: IMHO, this is a non-standard term. Apparently , some people use it but it could mean anything.

Comment: Actually this is a standard and common term in real-time computing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

release time is the earliest time when a job/task *can* start execution. the other term is deadline which is the time by which processing *must* be completed. the focus on "can" and "must" will realize you the actual meaning of these terms in scheduling.